# The isomorphism from $S_3/\langle (123)\rangle$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Suppose that $N=\{(123), (132), \operatorname{e}\}$ and $N$ is normal in $S_3$.  Show that the quotient group $S_3/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

What mapping should I use?

Comment: Do you know what the "sign" of a permutation is?

Comment: Just a note:  $|S_3/N|=2$. It is a fact that there is only one group up to isomorphism of order $2$.

Comment: Groups aren't normal, they are normal subgroups of other groups. So you probably mean, "If $N=\dots$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $S_3$..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you already know that $N$ is normal, then you have that $S_3/N$ is a group of order $2$, and hence the only option is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. If you want to give the explicit mapping that does that do the following:

From a comment I just saw, I think you dont know what the elements in $S_3/N$ are. Remember, $S_3/N$ is the quotient group, whose elements are the right cosets of $N$. Note that since $S_3$ has order $6$, and $N$ has order $3$, then you only need two cosets. Namely, $N$ and $xN$ for some $x$ not in $N$. Then the set $\{N,xN\}$ forms a group. Then you need to send $N\rightarrow 0$ and $xN\rightarrow 1$, to obtain your mapping.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the details

Comment: @JamesBond I see you are new to the site. You have not accepted any of the answers to the questions you have posted. The way it works is that you should post a question whenever you are stuck at something (but you should try hard before asking here) and then ask the questions. When someone gives a satisfactory solution for the problem posted you accept and answer and the question will then be considered closed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The identity needs to be mapped to the identity. The other thing needs to be mapped to the other thing.

Comment: How do I know what elements are in S3/N

Comment: They are the cosets of $N$ in $S_3$. In particular, $N$ and $$\{(1\:2),(1\:3),(2\:3)\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$S_3/N=\{N,(12)N\}$.  Which one of these cosets is the identity under coset multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

First, by using Lagrange's theorem, we know the index $[S_3:N]=|S|/3=6/3=2$, so that will be the order of the quotient group...
Now the mapping between this and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is trivial because, under isomorphisms, there exists only one group of order 2. I will let you realize that, just think about it, if you have a group of only two elements, not a lot of things can happen...